# Let my youtube playlist play randomly

Tags: html, youtube

I want my youtube playlist or playlists to play randomly songs. Optimally, i want a buttom that can refresh the page, so a new song will come on.
I have tried alot and could only find something that playing 1 certain video.
Is it possible to shuffle a playlist from the start?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In theory, each video in the playlist is assigned an index value. There is a difference between shuffling and refreshing the page. You can make a shuffle button that acts as a boolean, if it's on then the NEXT song (index number) will be randomly generated from the playlist, excluding the current songs index value.

Your question is very detailed and not language specific so I can't really help you further but that is my take on the logic behind what you need to do. Happy to help but best I can do is take a reasonable guess.

Edit*: Sorry, didn't see your Javascript tag, unfortunately I don't know Javascript.